# how i can change title with RX index

Tags: swift3, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I want to change title with an observable int.

in view Model

```
var index = Variable<Int>(0)
```

in view Controller

```
let title = ["title1","title2","title3","title4","title5"]
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
self.viewModel.index.value = 0
    self.viewModel.index
        .asObservable()
        .map( {self.periodText[$0]
        })
        .bind(to: self.titleLabel.rx.text)

        .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}
```

When i do this i have an error in the blind(to) :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The function never pass in the .map

How i can change the title when my index change in RX Swift?

Answer (score 1):

The `textField` on the `storyBoard` doesn't connect to the `@IBOutlet titleLabel` which 
results in this error message.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `self.periodText` array does not have as many elements as your index value, thus running out of bounds.

Alternatively, it could be that you're defining your diposeBag as `self.disposeBag: DisposeBag!`. If you've then forgotten to create an instantiation of it before `viewWillAppear`, it is still set to nil, in which case you'll run into this error too.

Generally, it is best to share more details on where your error occurs, so it is easier to narrow it down.

Comment: my error is when i do .bind(to: self.periodLabel.rx.text) it's never pass in the map

Comment: I defining my diposeBag like  `let disposeBag = DisposeBag()`